# How to find when a string's letter matches a another's letter?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

For example, alpha and comp are the two string we are working with:

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
numhelp  12345678901234567890123456
comp = "this is an example"
```

How do I compare the `comp` to the `alpha` so that I get a new list, `index = []`, with the number or index of where each letter is in the string.

So the index for comp would look like `[20, 8, 9, 19....]` ignore spaces for now

And then is it possible for me to use those indexes in another list of letters?

```
key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
numhlp 12345678901234567890123456
```

So the final string looks like: `ULYJ....`

And then all we need to do is add the spaces from a space locations list that I am pretty sure I can create.

Sorry if that was poorly explained, hopefully you all understand. And thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by comparing?

Comment: this sounds like you are trying to perform some sort of cryptography encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string module has useful functionality for exactly this.

```
import string

alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
comp = "this is an example"

tr = string.maketrans(alpha, key)
print string.translate(comp.upper(), tr)
# -> ULYJ YJ XW TIXBAZT
```

Comment: +1 for `comp.translate()`. You could include `upper()` into the translation table: [`comp.makestrans(alpha+alpha.lower(), key+key.lower())`](http://ideone.com/Y78wox) -- it can produce lower and upper case output: use `key*2` to get only uppercase output. Note: you code is for Python 2 but the question has tag [tag:python-3.x]. Follow the link to see [Python 3 code](http://ideone.com/Y78wox)

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH. You guys were a HUGE help. I had a school project I had to do, and this method essentially solves the main problem I had. Thanks again! @J.F.Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

```
In [8]: alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

In [9]: comp = "this is an example"

In [10]: [1+alpha.find(letter.upper()) for letter in comp if letter != ' ']
Out[10]: [20, 8, 9, 19, 9, 19, 1, 14, 5, 24, 1, 13, 16, 12, 5]
```

And:

```
In [18]: indices = [1+alpha.find(letter.upper()) for letter in comp if letter != ' ']

In [19]: key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"

In [20]: ''.join(key[i-1] for i in indices)
Out[20]: 'ULYJYJXWTIXBAZT'
```

For strings and lists and other itemizable objects, Python uses an index origin of zero.

It is python's convention that the index origin is zero.  In the question, `numhlp` has index-origin of one.  That is why the `1+` and `-1` appear in the formulas above.  The next section below demonstrates this.

#### Direct conversion to encrypted form

If the goal is to get to the encrypted form, it is easy to go directly.  If we add a space to the beginning of alpha and key, we can even easily include the spaces as spaces:

```
In [33]: key = " XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"

In [34]: alpha = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

In [35]: ''.join(key[alpha.find(letter.upper())] for letter in comp)
Out[35]: 'ULYJ YJ XW TIXBAZT'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to sort of do a Substitution Cipher (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). If that's what you'r doing then finding the index might be more complicated than what you need to really do. How about just creating a mapping from letter to letter. Then you can run each letter in your string to encode through the lookup. Heck if it's not found you can even just put in a space instead.

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
comp = "this is an example"

translate = dict(zip(alpha, key)) #dictionary to translate from alpha to key
encoded = [translate.get(c.upper(), " ") for c in comp] # use the get to turn anything not matched into a space
print ''.join(encoded)

>>>ULYJ YJ XW TIXBAZT
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict to get the indexes and the key trasnlation:

comp = "this is an example"

```
key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV' '"
key_dict = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(key,1)}
index_dict = {k:v for v,k in enumerate("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' '",1)}

comp_ind = [index_dict[ch.upper()] for ch in comp if ch.upper() in index_dict]
print("".join(key_dict[k] for k in comp_ind))
ULYJ YJ XW TIXBAZT
```